# How to change color of Foundation 5 <select> dropdown triangle

Tags: svg, sass, zurb-foundation

Looking at the `_forms.scss` for Foundation 5, I see this code that generates the triangle on the  form element:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iM3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNiAzIiBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0ibmV3IDAgMCA2IDMiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iNS45OTIsMCAyLjk5MiwzIC0wLjAwOCwwICIvPjwvc3ZnPg==');
```

this generates a triangle that is black (and a little small for my tastes) and I would like to customize it.

I know I can resize it with the css `background-size` property, but I was wondering if there is a way that I can change the color of the triangle?
- Do I need to regenerate the base64-encoded svg+xml?
- If so, are there any good tools out there for generating?

As a side note, are there any recommendations for extending Foundation 5 .scss to be able to use a scss $variable to set the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you base64-decode the value, you'll get the following SVG data.

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        width="6px"
        height="3px"
        viewBox="0 0 6 3"
        enable-background="new 0 0 6 3"
        xml:space="preserve"
    >
        <polygon points="5.992,0 2.992,3 -0.008,0" />
    </svg>
```

If you wanted the change the color to red, for example, you'll add a `style` attribute with a `fill` declaration for the [polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    width="6px"
    height="3px"
    viewBox="0 0 6 3"
    enable-background="new 0 0 6 3"
    xml:space="preserve"
>
    <!-- red triangle -->
    <polygon
        points="5.992,0 2.992,3 -0.008,0"
        style="fill:red;"
    />
</svg>
```

Then encode it back to base64. You can use any online service, like base64decode.org, or use a function in your language of choice, like [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) or [PHP](https://www.php.net/base64_encode), etc

SVG elements can also be styled with CSS and have classes and id attributes. (Though I'm not sure if it works for base64 encoded elements).

Comment: [base64decode.org](http://base64decode.org) is a great resource and exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!